# jQuery datepicker, show month after calling onChangeMonthYear

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Basically what I'm wanting is my datepicker to echo out the month that it just changed to after selecting a new month. My code is currently:

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        onChangeMonthYear: function () {
           $('#date').text("Changed Month to: " + *what to put here*);
        }
   });
});
```

I've tried everything I can think of, but the only thing I can even get me to return a month is if I get it from the date via $(this).val(), but that only returns me the month of the selected date, whereas I just want to know when the month is changed, and what it was changed to. Any help steering me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) { var date = new Date(year, month - 1); alert(date)}
```

Use this code this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

**From jQuery UI Documentation**

Allows you to define your own event when the datepicker moves to a new month and/or year. The function receives the selected year, month (1-12), and the datepicker instance as parameters. this refers to the associated input field.

Code examples

Supply a callback function to handle the onChangeMonthYear event as an init option.

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) { ... }
});
```

As you can see from above, there are 3 input params that you're omitting in your code.